# Пунктуация в предложении "Смотришь на них как в тени..."

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

"Смотришь на них как в тени, хочешь угадать их речи, их думы, их заботы по движениям, — внимаешь очами, и любопытство растет до горячего участия".

Объясните, пожалуйста, постановку запятой с тире в оном предложении, а также отсутствие запятой перед частицей "как".

Comment: Если Вы задаёте вопрос по цитате из какого-то произведения, лучше сразу говорить об этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант редактирования:

***Смотришь на них, как на тЕни***, хочешь угадать их речи, их думы, их заботы по движениям, — **внимаешь очами**, и любопытство растет до горячего участия.

Постановка знаков препинания

1) *Смотришь на них,  как на тени* — сравнительный оборот.

2) **Запятая и тире как единый знак** после распространенного однородного ряда перед обобщающим словом (внимаешь очами). Авторский знак, используется при делении предложения на смысловые части, если есть такая необходимость.

Comment: Наверно, "как в тени" означает плохую видимость - плохое понимание чего-то (покрыто тайной, тенью), а дальше говорится про стремление это понять. И ещё, однородный ряд заканчивается на слове "заботы", а "по движениям" уже относится (по смыслу) ко всем трём предыдущим элементам.

Comment: 1) Кто у вас в тенИ?  Люди в "ином свете" скорее сами кажутся тенями. 2) Смотришь, хочешь угадать, - как бы внимаешь очами.  Единый знак обобщает всю предыдущую фразу.

Comment: 1) Может быть: *смотришь на них, будто они в тени* или *смотришь на них, будто находишься в тени*. Пытаюсь расшифровать смысл, не рассматривая опечатку. 2) Единый знак обобщает, если перед тире нужно что-то закрыть. А так - запятая поставлена неверно.

Comment: Не получится у вас расшифровать. И вообще, это художественный текст, а не кроссворд, он должен пониматься быстро и сразу. А если нет - то это погрешность стиля. И единый знак нужен, одним тире не обойдешься.

Comment: Не нужен. Он не ставится по желанию, а ставится, когда есть на то причины: однородный ряд (после последнего элемента) или нужно что-то закрыть.

Comment: Не нужен, так зачеркните. А мне вот нужен. Просто Вы работаете по формальным правилам (элементы считаете), а   я  - по смысловому и интонационному принципу (они-то поважнее будут).  И классики этот знак разрешают ставить, если предложение нужно поделить на смысловые блоки (так что я тоже действую по правилам).

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете суть. Правда в следующем: при "встрече" запятой и тире, если единое целое делится на смысловые блоки (или простое предложение делится, или одна часть ссылается на предыдущую). Но у нас этой "встречи" нет (так как нет оборота, который должен закрываться запятой). У классиков таких примеров тоже нет.

Comment: Ладно, oleedd, вы всё прочитали, два комментария я удаляю, разбирайтесь с единым знаком сами. Тема сложная,  требует серьезных размышлений, но не поспешных выводов и обобщений. За "вы неправы, как всегда" извините, обижать вас мне не хотелось.

Comment: Эта тема как раз таки очень требует обобщений. Розенталь их, к сожалению, не сделал. Есть такая книга (в интернете нет, может, можно найти в библиотеках): *Гришко Ф. Т. Наблюдения над употреблением сложного знака «запятая — тире»  // Рус. язык в школе. 1971. № 6*. Это один из источников, по которым Розенталь писал параграфы.

Comment: @Sharon Там суть вопроса была в том, что это цитата из книги Бестужева-Марлинского, которая с такой пунктуацией пережила множество изданий в самые разные годы (даже эпохи). Правда, в разных изданиях встречается то "на тени", то "в тени", но всюду без запятой перед "как".

Comment: @grizzly Спасибо за информацию. Я не очень понимаю сочетание"смотреть в тени", в современном языке его трудно признать корректным. Но в этом случае здесь запятая менее вероятна, так как оборот может считаться необособленным обстоятельством. Но вообще-то в таких случаях лучше указывать автора, как-никак 1830-е годы,  многое могло измениться в грамматике, лексике, пунктуации.